# What is sequence of $n$ numbers

Tags: number-theory

If $n = 3$, then sequence is

$$3\ 4\ 3$$

if $n = 4$, then sequence is

$$4\ 6\ 6\ 4$$

Then how could we find the sequence for any $n$ numbers.

Comment: Possible sequence is 5, 8, 8, 8, 5

Comment: Could you add more context around your question? Where is it from? Right now, it coulb be anything.

Comment: What's the sequence for $n \in \{1,2\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a wild guess. Without further explaination from OP, it is difficult to answer.

It could be from Pascal triangle
$$\begin{matrix}1\\1&1\\1&2&1\\1&3&3&1\\1&4&6&4&1\\\vdots\end{matrix}$$
Then, for $n$, take the $n$-th row and add $n-1$ to every number.

For $n=3$:
$$1+(3-1)\ 2+(3-1)\ 1+(3-1) \implies 3\ 4\ 3$$

For $n=4$:
$$1+(4-1)\ 3+(4-1)\ 3+(4-1)\ 1+(3-1) \implies 4\ 6\ 6\ 4$$

For $n=5$:
$$1+(5-1)\ 4+(5-1)\ 6+(5-1)\ 4+(5-1)\ 1+(5-1) \implies 5\ 8\ 10\ 8\ 5$$
It is farfetch, but fit OP question.

Answer (score 2):

In general, such questions are impossible to answer, but the
[OEIS sequence A003991](https://oeis.org/A003991) is the first
sequence with those consecutive values.
They are from the usual multiplication table
of positive integers read by antidiagonals.
The sequence begins
$$1,2,2,3,4,3,4,6,6,4,5,8,9,8,5,6,10,12,12,10,6,\dots$$
which comes from the table
$$ \begin{matrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \dots\\
 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 & \dots\\
 3 & 6 & 9 &12 & 15 & \dots\\
 4 & 8 & 12 &16 & 20 & \dots\\
 5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25 & \dots \\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \ddots\\
\end{matrix}$$
If I had to choose I would pick the simplest possible answer
and this seems to be it.